# Having issue in reading Input value from Table

Tags: javascript, html

Actually I am trying to read the input field value from HTML Table using querySelector in loop but i don't know why it is showing me error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null".

I also tried it with this :- `oCells.item(j).getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value  Same Result`:- "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Please help me getting what I am doing wrong here,

Thanks

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table id="m-table">
   <caption>Item Lists</caption>
  <thead class="text-center">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Item Code</th>
      <th scope="col">Item Description</th>
      <th scope="col">Rate</th>
      <th scope="col">Order Qty</th>
      <th scope="col">Order Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">Rate of Rec. Qty</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity Received</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id = "PO_results">
     <tr class = "aach-Result">
      <th class = "rowInd" scope="row">1</th>
      <td class = "IC">2</td>
      <td class = "ID">3</td>
      <td class = "IR">4</td>
      <td class = "OQ">5</td>
      <td class = "OAM">6</td>
      <td>
      <div >
      <input id = "1" type="number"   aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"  min="1" required>
      </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      <div >
      <span id="inputGroup-sizing-sm"></span>
      <input id = "2" type="number"  aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"  min="1" required>
      </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr class = "aach-Result">
      <th class = "rowInd" scope="row">2</th>
      <td class = "IC">3</td>
      <td class = "ID">4</td>
      <td class = "IR">5</td>
      <td class = "OQ">6</td>
      <td class = "OAM">7</td>
      <td>
      <div >
      <input id = "1" type="number"   aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"  min="1" required>
      </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      <div >
      <span id="inputGroup-sizing-sm"></span>
      <input id = "2" type="number"  aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"  min="1" required>
      </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
      <th id="LinesTableGRN" colspan="7">Total Amount</th>
      <td> <input id = "TotalTableGRN" type="number"  min="1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick = "ProcessGETable()">


   <script>
   function ProcessGETable()
   {
    var Tdata = [];
 
    var oTable = document.getElementById('m-table');
    var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;
    for (i = 1; i < rowLength; i++)
    {
    var row = [];         
       var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;        
       var cellLength = oCells.length;
      
       for(var j = 1; j < cellLength-1; j++)
       {
              if(j < 5)
              {
              var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML;
              row.push(cellVal);
              }
              else
              {
              var test =  oCells.item(j).querySelector('input');
              console.log(test.value)
              }
        }
         Tdata.push(row)
    }
  console.log(Tdata)
   }
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above error is happening cause the last column while running the for loop is referring to 'Order Amount' column which doesn't contain input element. Hence this line `oCells.item(j).querySelector('input')` will be null. To get the 'Rate of Rec. Qty' change `if(j < 5)` to `if(j < 6)`.

If you want to get both 'Rate of Rec. Qty' and 'Quantity Received' then also change `for(var j = 1; j < cellLength-1; j++)` to `for(var j = 1; j < cellLength; j++)`.

This change should eliminate the error you are facing and will return the values.
Please verify..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table id="m-table">
   <caption>Item Lists</caption>
  <thead class="text-center">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Item Code</th>
      <th scope="col">Item Description</th>
      <th scope="col">Rate</th>
      <th scope="col">Order Qty</th>
      <th scope="col">Order Amount</th>
      <th scope="col">Rate of Rec. Qty</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity Received</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id = "PO_results">
     <tr class = "aach-Result">
      <th class = "rowInd" scope="row">1</th>
      <td class = "IC">2</td>
      <td class = "ID">3</td>
      <td class = "IR">4</td>
      <td class = "OQ">5</td>
      <td class = "OAM">6</td>
      <td>
      <div >
      <input id = "1" type="number"   aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"  min="1" required>
      </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      <div >
      <span id="inputGroup-sizing-sm"></span>
      <input id = "2" type="number"  aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"  min="1" required>
      </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr class = "aach-Result">
      <th class = "rowInd" scope="row">2</th>
      <td class = "IC">3</td>
      <td class = "ID">4</td>
      <td class = "IR">5</td>
      <td class = "OQ">6</td>
      <td class = "OAM">7</td>
      <td>
      <div >
      <input id = "1" type="number"   aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"  min="1" required>
      </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      <div >
      <span id="inputGroup-sizing-sm"></span>
      <input id = "2" type="number"  aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"  min="1" required>
      </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
      <th id="LinesTableGRN" colspan="7">Total Amount</th>
      <td> <input id = "TotalTableGRN" type="number"  min="1" disabled></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick = "ProcessGETable()">


   <script>
   function ProcessGETable()
   {
    var Tdata = [];
 
    var oTable = document.getElementById('m-table');
    var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;
    for (i = 1; i < rowLength; i++)
    {
    var row = [];         
       var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;        
       var cellLength = oCells.length;
      
       for(var j = 1; j < cellLength; j++)
       {
              if(j < 6)
              {
              var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML;
              row.push(cellVal);
              }
              else
              {
              var test =  oCells.item(j).querySelector('input');
              console.log(test.value)
              }
        }
         Tdata.push(row)
    }
  console.log(Tdata)
   }
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. that was a silly mistake from my side:P. Thanks again for correcting it.